# instantiating a class template and call its methods

Tags: c++, templates, header-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

When I include MyClass.h and do:

```
MyClass<int, int> ccc = MyClass<int, int>();
ccc.myMethod1(3, 4);
```

I get a lot of errors telling undefined reference to constructor and methods ... However when I include MyClass.cpp (which is not a proper why to code) there is no error ! How to fix that ?

I'm compiling under Code::Blocks using g++

Comment: See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/20984).

Comment: maybe you intended at line 1 **MyClass<int, int> ccc;**

Comment: @chac is there any difference between **MyClass<int, int> ccc;** and **MyClass<int, int> ccc = MyClass<int, int>();** ? It's like **vector<int> v;** and **vector<int> v = vector<int>();** it's the same thing I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that template classes are not compiled, only instantiated templates will be compiled.

Rule of thumb: don't place template implementations in a `cpp` file but either directly in the header or another file included by the header (if you want to part implementation from the interface).

E.g:

myclass.h

```
template<typename A>
class MyClass
{
    ...
};

#include "myclass.inc"
```

myclass.inc

```
//implementation goes here: 
....
```